# Laravel how to get the selected id from form and update the form in real-time

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I don't know what would be a proper title about this problem. So, I have a form where you can book an appointment to do the vaccination. Every vaccination center has its specific vaccine type, so I was thinking about how to update the form in real-time after a user selects a vaccination center in the form.

This is a part of the code in the form:

```html
<form action="/citizen/add/appointment" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <label for="vaccination_center">Vaccination Center</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="vaccination_center" name="vaccination_center" required focus>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Vaccination Center</option>
        @foreach($centers as $name)
        <option value={{ $name->id }}>{{ $name->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <br>
    <p>NOTE: Every Vaccination center has different vaccine type</p>
    <label for="vaccination_id">Vaccination</label>
    <!-- Later I should show vaccine that are in the specific vac_center-->
    <select class="form-control" id="vaccination_id" name="vaccination_id" required focus>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Vaccine type</option>
        @foreach($vaccination as $vac)
        <option value={{ $vac->id }}>{{ $vac->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <br>
```

This is the code in the controller:

```
public function book()
{
    $center = VaccinationCenters::all();
    $vaccinations = Vaccinations::all();
    //Below is what I am trying to make
    $vac = DB::table('vaccination')
        ->join('vaccination_center_has_vaccination', 'vaccination.id', '=', 'vaccination_center_has_vaccination.vaccination_id')
        ->select('vaccination.*')
        //->where('vaccination_center_id is selected from the form')
        ->get();

    return view('citizen.book')
        ->with(['centers' => $center])
        ->with(['vaccination' => $vaccinations]);
}
```

This code of the form below should show only the vaccine type that are in that specific vaccination center that the user just selected:

```html
<select class="form-control" id="vaccination_id" name="vaccination_id" required focus>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Vaccine type</option>
    @foreach($vaccination as $vac)
        <option value={{ $vac->id }}>{{ $vac->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: you most likely want to fetch your list of options for vaccination_id's from the vaccination_center via ajax.  This would be a great spot to use vuejs and axios.

Comment: check out this demo (I believe its just jquery) but its populating a select from a previous select via ajax. https://makitweb.com/demos/auto-populate-dropdown-with-jquery-ajax